# How to export apps in AppGyver Steroids to App Store

Tags: steroids

So I've spent some time developing an app based on my webpage and have run into a problem. I have no idea how to export the app from AppGyver Steroids. Their scanner apps which sends it to my phone works flawlessly, but I can't for the my life find any clue as to how to get the file I need to submit to App Store out of the Steroids environment.

Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's working in the scanner the next step is to deploy it to Appgyver and then follow the build process for Android or iOS.

To deploy your app to the Appgyver cloud go to your terminal and in your project directory type `steroids deploy`.

After you've deployed it to Appgyver you can access it by visiting cloud.appgyver.com/applications.

Then follow the steps here to create the apk file for publishing to Android:
http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/build-service/build-settings/build-settings-for-android/

Or here for iOS:
http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/build-service/build-settings/build-settings-for-ios/

Comment: "You have successfully added your application to the App Store. You will receive an email when your application has been approved. You can also log in to iTunes Connect at any time to check the status of your applications." Thanks!